# Creating a PHP Sticky Form

Tags: php, html

im trying to create a sticky form in php with text box, text area, radio button group, checkbox group, and drop down list. I managed to get the sticky part working with the textbox, but for everything else, it either doesnt save on reload or it doesnt display the content after the specific element. For example, the my code below, nothing shows up after the `Male` radio button. Just the text "Male", but nothing after that. Im not sure what i am doing wrong and im not sure how to make the remaining elements sticky (text area, checkbox and radio buttons).

```
<?php
function display_form()
{
   $self = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
   global $nameErr,$emailErr,$subjectErr,$commentErr,$termErr;
   $name = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : '';
   $email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '';  
   $subject = isset($_POST['subject']) ? $_POST['subject'] : '';
   $comment = isset($_POST['comment']) ? $_POST['comment'] : '';
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .error {color: #FF0000;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Contact Us</h1>
<form action="<?php echo $self ?>" method="POST">
    <span class="error"> <?php echo "* Required Field(s)";?></span>
    <br><br>
        Name: <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name?>">
    <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
        <br><br>
        E-Mail: <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email?>">
    <span class="error">* <?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
        <br><br>
       Gender: Male <input type="radio" <?php if($gender==="Male") echo "selected='selected'"; ?> name="gender" value="Male">
       Female <input type="radio" <?php if($gender==="Female") echo "selected='selected'"; ?> name="gender" value="Female">

       <br><br>
       Subject: <select name="subject">
        <option value="select">Select...</option>
            <option value="useraccount">User Account</option>
            <option value="reportabuse">Report Abuse</option>
            <option value="reporterror">Report Error</option>
            <option value="jobs">Jobs</option>
            <option value="other">Other</option>
        </select>
    <span class="error">* <?php echo $subjectErr;?></span>
        <br><br>
        Comment: <textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea>
    <span class="error">* <?php echo $commentErr;?></span>
        <br><br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="terms"><label>I understand the <a href="">Terms and Policies</a></label>
    <span class="error">* <?php echo $termErr;?></span> 
    <br>                
        <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="subscribe"><label>Subscribe to our Monthly Newsletters</label>
        <br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="button" value="Submit">
    </form>

</body>
</html>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: what does  check($gender,"Male") do?

Comment: from what searched, it supposed to select Male if it was select previously. So basically, making the radio button sticky

Comment: I dont think so there is any built in function like tha in php..You need to write some login to do that..remove check function for both and try to see if it is resolved or not.

Comment: ok, but then there is still the problem of making the form fully sticky.

Comment: add this  <input type="radio" <?php if($gender==="Male") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>  name="gender" value="Male"> ..do the same thing for female..if the $gender will have male value, it will auto select it

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo that didnt work :( . The modified code is above.

Comment: dude, you are not calling this function that is why you can see anything..

Comment: call this function or remove function display_form() { and } at the end

Comment: what do u mean? the function is called initially.

Comment: you are declaring it but not calling it..

Comment: i do, the above code is not the full code,  only the form part, the form is displayed like it supposed to, but im having trouble making the data entered stay for the checkbox, textarea and radio button.

Comment: fixed it..posted it in the answer...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70359/discussion-between-danyal-sandeelo-and-shadowviper).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the check-boxes with this code

```
 Gender: Male <input type="radio" name="gender" <?php if($gender=="Male") echo"checked='checked'";?>value="Male"> 
 Female <input type="radio" name="gender"  <?php if($gender=="Female") echo"checked='checked'";?> value="Female">
```

Comment: I tested it bro, let's talk on chat!